# Print HashMap Objects on a 2-dimensional grid

Tags: java, hashmap

It's a simplified code snippet I need to use in a Conway's Game of Life implementation. I have a HashMap where the Coord Objects ( cells in Game of Life ) are stored. Coord objects are pairs of X, Y coordinates which I want to print on a simple 2D grid.

I have problems with the `printGrid(HashMap<Coord, Integer> map)` method, mainly:

1. Is there a simpler and more elegant way to print the Coord objects on a 2-dimensinal grid?
2. If not, is there a way to check if there is a Coord object with given X,Y parameters in the HashMap without creating an instance of the Coord object for every X,Y position on the grid like I'm doing here:

   ```
   if (map.containsKey(new Coord(column,row))) {
       grid +=  map.get(new Coord(column,row));
   } else {
       grid += "#";
   }
   ```

The code:

```
public class Main {

    static class Coord {
        int x;
        int y;

        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            Coord c = (Coord) o;
            return c.x == x && c.y == y;
        }

        public Coord(int x, int y) {
            super();
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int hashCode() {
            return x * 3 + y * 5;
        }
    }

    public static String printGrid(HashMap<Coord, Integer> map) {

        int grid_width = 10;
        int grid_height = 10;       
        String grid = "";

        for(int row =0; row < grid_height; row++) {
            for(int column=0; column< grid_width; column++) {
                if(map.containsKey(new Coord(column,row))) {
                    grid +=  map.get(new Coord(column,row));
                } else {
                    grid += "#";
                }
            }
            grid += "\n"; // next row
        }

        return grid;        
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {        

        HashMap<Coord, Integer> map = new HashMap<Coord, Integer>();

        map.put(new Coord(0, 0), 1);
        map.put(new Coord(1, 2), 5);
        map.put(new Coord(3, 4), 1);
        map.put(new Coord(4, 5), 3);
        map.put(new Coord(4, 6), 2);        

        System.out.println(printGrid(map));
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain why you are using a `Map`. Do you need to have an arbitrarily large grid?

Comment: Yes, it should work for very big grids. That is the reason why I want to store only the live cells. I thought HashMap would be a good datastructure for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following code match your requirements.Basically you can create a StringBuilder object and initialize it with all '#'. Then, based on Coord objects in the map replace the corresponding character in the builder with the value in the map.It is simple and you don't need to create a Coord object for each grid cell.

```
public static String printGrid(HashMap<Coord, Integer> map) {

int width = 10;
int height = 10;

int lenght = height * width ;

StringBuilder grid = new StringBuilder(lenght);     

// Initialize the builder
int i = 0 ;
  while(i<lenght){
    if(i >= width && i%(width)==0){
            grid.append('\n');
    }
   grid.append('#');        
  i++;
 }

for(Coord c : map.keySet()){
    int index = c.x *(width + 1) + c.y;
      grid.setCharAt(index, map.get(c).toString().charAt(0));
}

 return grid.toString();        
}
```

output:

```
  1#########
  ##5#######
  ##########
  ####1#####
  #####32###
  ##########
  ##########
  ##########
  ##########
  ##########
```

hope this can help.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is close to what you want, but:

- Since the grid is very big, how would `printGrid()` know the size? You should pass the size in as parameters too.
- Don't create the `Coord` object twice. Only create it once and assign to variable, so it can be used twice.
  *This point is negated by the next bullet, but point well made, right?*
- Don't call `containsKey()`, then `get()`. Since your map will not have null values (according to the way you used it), the null returned by `get()` is enough of an existence test.
- Do not do `string += string` in a loop. Use a `StringBuilder`. Huge performance difference when string gets large.

So, your code becomes:

```
public static String printGrid(HashMap<Coord, Integer> map, int width, int height) {

    StringBuilder grid = new StringBuilder(height * (width + 1)); // Pre-sizing is optional, but
                                                                  // may improve performance a bit

    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < width; column++) {
            Integer value = map.get(new Coord(column, row));
            if (value != null) {
                grid.append(value);
            } else {
                grid.append('#');
            }
        }
        grid.append('\n'); // next row
    }

    return grid.toString();
}
```

Comment: Good points made, thank you very much for your insights!
Any ideas how to print the Coords without having to instantiate (X * Y) objects? How could I acomplish something like this:

1. Iterate through all HashMap objects and store the Coord.x and Coord.y attributes in an Array[][] or some similar datastructure.
2. "Plot" the stored x,y coordinates on the X * Y grid.

Answer (score 0):

Considering Andreas' suggestion, here is my proposition

Add **int neighbours** in the **Coord** class

```
static class Coord {
    int x;
    int y;
    int neighbours;

    public Coord(int x, int y) {
        this(x, y, 0);
    }

    public Coord(int x, int y, int neighbours) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.neighbours = neighbours;
    }

    // getters and setters here

    // Equals method here

}
```

Add a method to retrieve a Coord object from coordinates

```
Coord getCoord(HashSet<Coord> data, int x, int y) {
    Coord coord = new Coord(x, y);
    if (data.contains(coord)) {
        for (Coord c : data) {
            if (c.equals(coord)){
                return c;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Your **printGrid** method will be like this

```
String printGrid(HashSet<Coord> data, int width, int height) {
    StringBuilder grid = new StringBuilder(height * (width + 1));
    Coord coord;

    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < width; column++) {
            coord = getCoord(data, row, column);
            if(coord != null) {
                grid.append(coord.getNeighbours());
            } else {
                grid.append('#');
            }
        }
        grid.append('\n'); // next row
    }

    return grid.toString();        
}
```

And in your **main** method you will have this

```
HashSet<Coord> data = new HashSet<>();

data.add(new Coord(0, 0, 1));
data.add(new Coord(1, 2, 5));
data.add(new Coord(3, 4, 1));
data.add(new Coord(4, 5, 3));
data.add(new Coord(4, 6, 2));        

System.out.println(printGrid(data, 10, 10));
```

You can also use **ArrayList** like this

```
Coord getCoordWithList(ArrayList<Coord> data, int x, int y) {
    Coord coord = new Coord(x, y);
    int index = data.indexOf(coord);
    if (index > -1) {
        return data.get(index);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well instead of having a map with **Coord** object as key, you can use a String as key. Your String key will be the concatenation of **x** and **y** values of your **Coord**.

So you will have this

```
for (int row = 0; row < grid_height; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < grid_width; column++) {
        String key = column + "#" + row;
        if(map.containsKey(key)) {
            grid += map.get(key) + "";
        } else {
            grid += "#";
        }
    }
    grid += "\n"; // next row
}
```

And for the initialisation of the map you will have this

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

map.put("0#0", 1);
map.put("1#2", 5);
map.put("3#4", 1);
map.put("4#5", 3);
map.put("4#6", 2);        

System.out.println(printGrid(map));
```

## Edit

Instead of using a HashMap to store your data, you can just use a HashSet for it. The **Integer** value of the map will be an attribute of your **Coord** class

Comment: Using `String` instead of a `Coord` is not an improvement. It is in fact a performance and size degradation. Creating a `String` is slower than creating a `Coord`, and the `String` will take up more memory.

Comment: The Coord is only an example class.  I need to store a object in the `key`. It will have more parameters, such as **DEAD,ALIVE** field. Number of neighbours will be stored in the `<integer>` value of HashMap item.

Comment: Well then I don't think you need a HashMap to store your data. A HashSet will be sufficient

Comment: @SouleymanRapaya you're right, a HashSet would be sufficient. But taking OOP design in consideration i think the Coord should not have the information about the neighboring Coord objects. I could be wrong or too strict object oriented though.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem since it's just and **Integer**